# Update Wordpress posts via SQL if they are in certain category?

Tags: sql, wordpress, categories, posts

I need to append something to post content if posts are in a certain category.
Here's the code I have to show all the posts in the category.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON
(wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON
(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 1
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

I need to write an update query to append post content. Here's that:

```
UPDATE Table SET Field=CONCAT(Field,'your extra html');
```

How do I write an update query with the results from the select query?

Answer (score 0):

It may help you:

`UPDATE wp SET Field=CONCAT(Field,'your extra html') 
WHERE wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 1
ORDER BY post_date DESC`